# $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges and $f(x),g(x)$ continuous and bounded in $[0,\infty)$, must $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I am trying to disprove the claim in the title of this question:

> If $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges and $f(x),g(x)$ are continuous, bounded functions in $[0,\infty)$, $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$ converges.

But I can't find any counterexamples.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why you think it is wrong?

Comment: Mostly because it appeared in a set of two questions, the second of which is true ;). So the statement is correct, then? I'll try to prove it instead.

Comment: there might be a reason why you cannot find a counterexample. Did you try to prove the statement?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind in regards to a proof. The intuition behind it being wrong is also that the equivalent claim for series is wrong.

Comment: Another reason why it seems wrong is that the Dirchlet test seems to 'demand' a lot more, but here we don't demand much of f and g.

Comment: @mixedmath: $(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @josh: then you can find a counterexample similar to the one for series? (hint: $f(x)$ has to be oscillating)

Comment: I know $f$ has to be oscillating... but I can't think of any trigonometrical trick that would be the equivalent of $(-1)^n$ in series, and keep continuity.

Comment: It seems like $sin(x)/\sqrt(x)$ ought to work, but I can't prove it. I'll think about that.

Comment: Okay, I got it. It took noticing that $sin^2(x)=1-cos(2x)$

Comment: the integral of $\sin(x)/\sqrt{x}$ converges. To prove it, split the integral up in pieces $[n \pi, (n+1)\pi]$ ...

Comment: One doesn't even need $f$ to be oscillating: suppose $f= 1$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(x) = x^{-3/2}$ for $x> 0$. Can you multiply $f$ by function that destroys the convergence of the $x^{-3/2}$ part?

Comment: @josh: if you have solved it please add an answer to your question.

Comment: @Fabian: I cannot, being a guest user. Could any one of you write an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @JerryGagelman: I can't think of a bounded function that does this.  Presumably if $f(x)$ is absolutely convergent then $f(x)g(x)$ is also absolutely convergent, so I think it might not exist?

Comment: @josh : you're right. I was (wrongly) thinking about functions on a bounded interval when I hurriedly wrote that comment. That's math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}x$, $g(x)=\sin x$. Then $f,g$ satisfy your hypothesis. But 
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}x\,dx=\infty.
$$
To see this, consider the points $\{(2k+1)\pi/2:\ k\in\mathbb{N}\}$; there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\sin^2 t\geq 1/2$ for all $t\in [(2k+1)\pi/2-\delta, (2k+1)\pi/2+\delta]$. Then
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}x\,dx\geq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{(2k+1)\pi/2-\delta}^{(2k+1)\pi/2+\delta}\frac1{4x}\,dx\geq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2\delta}{4[(2k+1)\pi/2+\delta]}=\infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Take a function $f$ whose graph consists of spikes centered at the positive integers that do not overlap, together with portions of the $x$-axis, with the following properties:

- The area bounded by the $n$th spike and the $x$-axis is less than $1\over n$.
- The area of the "squared spike" is greater than ${1\over2n}$.
- Spikes centered at odd positive integers are above the $x$-axis
- Spikes centered at even positive integers are  below the $x$-axis.

Then $\int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx$ converges (it can be computed as a convergent alternating series).  Now consider $g=f$.

I believe $f(x)=g(x)=\sin(x^2)$ furnishes an example (it has properties similar to the above).

Comment: Does $sin(x^2)$ converge in $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @DavidMitra: $\int_0^\infty \sin^2(x^2)\,dx$ does not converge, just substituting $u=x^2$ leads to an integral similar to the one in my answer (with $\sqrt{u}$ in the denominator).

Comment: @josh Yes. It's graph consists of the "alternating above/below the $x$-axis" spikes as above . But the area of the spikes heads towards zero as $x$ heads towards infinity (the amplitude of a spike is always $1$; but the width of the spikes become small, because for large x it doesn't take much to get $x^2$ to range over an interval of length $2\pi$). The integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)\,dx$ can be computed as a convergent alternating series. According to WA, $\int_0^\infty \sin^2(x^2)\,dx$  seems to diverge. And so it does. See Martin's comment above.

Comment: @MartinArgerami It seems that the conclusion is right in a finite interval, but it is not right in a infinite interval. Can you give me an intuitive recognition?

Comment: @DavidMitra It seems that the conclusion is right in a finite interval, but it is not right in a infinite interval. Can you give me an intuitive recognition?

Comment: @Gingerjin I'm not sure what you're referring to. The integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2)\, dx$ converges. I imagine one can show that $\int_1^\infty \sin^2(x^2)\, dx ={1\over2}\int_1^\infty {\sin(u)\over \sqrt u}\, du  $ diverges by comparing it with the integral in Martin's example.