# $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\, dx$ converges absolutely and $g(x)$ is continuous and bounded on $[a, \infty)$.

Tags: integration, solution-verification, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

If $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\, dx$ converges absolutely and $g(x)$ is continuous and bounded on $[a, \infty)$, then $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)g(x)\, dx$ converges.

Is this statement true or false?

I know that this statement is [false if $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\, dx$ merely converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113423/int-0-infty-fxdx-converges-and-fx-gx-continuous-and-bounded-in)—take $f(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $g(x) = \sin{x}$.  However, I believe this statement is true for absolute convergence.  Is the following proof correct?  Thank you.

*Proof*.  Let $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\, dx$ converge absolutely and $g(x)$ be continuous and bounded on $[a,\infty)$.  Let $M\in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $|g(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in [a, \infty)$.  Then, $x\mapsto |f(x)\, g(x)|$ and $x\mapsto |M\, f(x)|$ are continuous on any closed interval $[a,b]\subset [a, \infty)$, and
$$
0\le |f(x)\, g(x)|\le |M f(x)|
$$
on $[a,\infty)$.  So, by the comparison test, since
$$
\int_a^{\infty} |M f(x)|\, dx = |M| \int_a^{\infty} |f(x)|\, dx \;\mbox{ converges}
,$$
we have that
$$
\int_a^{\infty} |f(x)\, g(x)|\, dx \;\mbox{ converges}
.$$

Comment: I guess you mean $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$ in your statement.